# How to make Android ButtonBar more visible in Holo.Light

Tags: android, styles

Currently I'm using a `ButtonBar` in my App (Holo Light Theme) but it isn't good to see.

A Screenshot:

[image]

The buttons at the bottom are those from the ButtonBar.

Here my XML Code for the ButtonBar:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBackAe"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="goBack"
        android:text="@string/btnBackAe" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSaveAe"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="saveData"
        android:text="@string/btnSaveAe" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a way to make them more visible and keep the `Holo Light` style?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own button backgrounds like the following:

/drawable/btn_hintergrund.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="#00C0C0" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="#00C0C0" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_hovered="true"
          android:drawable="#ECEAEB" /> <!-- hovered -->
    <item android:drawable="#ECEAEB" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

And add:

```
android:background="@drawable/btn_hintergrund"
```

to all these two buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! But is the design above really displayed as it meant to be?

Comment: Yes I did. It looks better, thanks for this!(with some improvments of your code, need to create a colors.xml, the code above doesn't work). But I'm still not happy about it :-/ Isn't there a way to create the same bar as in Google Chrome when saving a favorite.